# Specify one series to be plotted on the secondary y axis

Tags: python, altair

Say I have some data in a long format.  There are three series represented by keys `a`, `b` and `c`.

The values of `c` are an order of magnitude higher than those of `a` and `b`.

In the following plot, is there a (simple) way to specify that `c` should be plotted on the secondary y axis?

```py
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = (
    pd.DataFrame({
        'a': np.random.rand(10),
        'b': np.random.rand(10),
        'c': np.random.rand(10) * 10,
    })
    .stack()
    .to_frame('value')
    .reset_index()
)
df.columns = ['index', 'key', 'value']

(
    alt.Chart(df)
    .mark_line()
    .encode(x='index', y='value', color='key')
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert and I'm sure there are more efficient approaches. I used a filter to layer each graph and added an independent setting for the y-axis.

```
import altair as alt
from altair import datum
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(20200113)
df = (
    pd.DataFrame({
        'a': np.random.rand(10),
        'b': np.random.rand(10),
        'c': np.random.rand(10) * 10,
    })
    .stack()
    .to_frame('value')
    .reset_index()
)
df.columns = ['index', 'key', 'value']

base = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x='index',
    y='value',
    color='key:N'
    ).transform_filter(
    (datum.key == 'a') | (datum.key =='b')
)

line = alt.Chart(df).mark_line(color='#57A44C').encode(
    x='index',
    y=alt.Y('value', axis=alt.Axis(title='value')),
    color='key'
).transform_filter(
    (datum.key == 'c')
)

alt.layer(base, line).resolve_scale(
    y = 'independent'
)
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, this is great!  I was looking for something like a `transform_filter`, but my Google-fu failed me.

Comment: For more information about [filters](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/filter.html), please see here. If my answer was helpful to you, please accept the answer.

Comment: Done!  Thanks.  Any chance you know how to align the zeros on both `y` axes?  (Ie, if my data series have positive and negative values, it'd be much easier to read the chart if the zeros on the left and right axes were vertically aligned.)

Comment: This can be done by setting the 0 setting for the y-axis scale to false. `y=alt.Y('value', axis=alt.Axis(title='value'), scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),`